# how to get current user id in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I used this code in Laravel 5.4 to get the current logged in user id

```
    $id = User::find(Auth::id());
    dd($id);
```

but I receive "Null"

Answer (score 64):

**You may access the authenticated user via the Auth facade:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...

$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...

$id = Auth::id();
```

**You may access the authenticated user via an Illuminate\Http\Request**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function update(Request $request)
{
     $request->user(); //returns an instance of the authenticated user...
     $request->user()->id; // returns authenticated user id. 
}
```

**via the Auth helper function:**

```
auth()->user();  //returns an instance of the authenticated user...
auth()->user()->id ; // returns authenticated user id.
```

Comment: Your answer is so nice.....Keep it up......

Comment: ```Auth::user()``` executes a query. ```Auth::id()``` doesn't. Thank you, I didn't know Auth::id() existed.

Comment: Which one is better?

Comment: @PonzioPilato The third one is the best if you're using it within blade templates.

Answer (score 28):

You have to call `user()` method:

```
$id = \Auth::user()->id;
```

Or, if you want to get only the model:

```
$user = \Auth::user();
```

Comment: `User::find(\Auth::user()->id);` does not get the ID, and it's redundant. `Auth::user()->id` gets the id

Comment: He is not meant that

Answer (score 13):

### Using Helper:

```
auth()->user()->id ;   // or get name - email - ...
```

### Using Facade:

```
\Auth::user()->id ;   // or get name - email - ...
```

### Using DI Container:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
class MyClass
{
    private $authManager;
    public __construct(AuthManager $authManager)
    {
        $this->authManager = $authManager;
    }
}
```